# Save changes temporarily in git without committing

Tags: git

Can anyone suggest to save my work on git temporarily as I have lost my 15 days work because of machine failure. Git stash is not useful as it saves data locally and committing for 30 days and then merge is also not good idea as when we want to move data to production there will be 30-40 commits. Is there any way to save work temporarily and access from other system.

Comment: You should know that `git commit` actually makes commits under the hood.  Committing your work in some way or other is really the only practical option.

Comment: You can add as many remotes as you want. So, you could add a second remote for backups and push to the production remote only when you are ready to do so, otherwise you push to the backup remote only.

Comment: Just make commits. They're low cost. Make branches to remember those commits; branches are so low cost as to be almost free.

Comment: Read about [git workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow). It's ok to have 100s of commits in a branch. When you merge to master you can squash merge or squash before you merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary branch for this purpose.  You can `commit` and  `push` it to the remote, to access it from different systems. As you said, if committing for 30 days, there will be `30+` commits.

We can squash them to one single commit using the `git squash` command.

After that, you can `merge` this commit to your production also:

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~[30]
```

This would combine your last 30 commits into one.

Answer (score 2):

Make a new branch for these temporary changes with a significant name showing that this branch is like a draft. When you return to continue your work, merge it to your original working branch and destroy the draft one.

Comment: This requires committing, which the OP explicitly does not want.

Comment: What I understood is that he doesn't want to push his temporary work to the working branch and he misused the word "commit" to describe that. 
He wants to save this temporary work somewhere safe outside his local machine, and saving any work remotely cannot be done without committing.

Answer (score 0):

following trick might help:

1-you can create a diff file: e.g by command: git diff > temp.diff

2-commit it and push to server

3-in another machine pull and apply the diff by command : git apply temp.diff

4-loop through until finish your task

5-at the end you can delete the temp.diff file and commit real changes

Comment: There may be multiple files and creating those is not a good idea I think

Comment: This requires committing, which the OP explicitly does not want.

Answer (score 0):

Committing is *the* way to save changes in Git. Since you dis-allow committing, there is really nothing else that can be done, at least not within Git.

Of course, there are lots of things that can be done *outside* Git, backups being one of them. As the old saying goes: all important data has backups, and if you don't have backups, then your data wasn't that important to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people might want to avoid committing for whatever reason especially when working in a team, because you want to have a nice git history, or you don't want to logically split your work into multiple commits.

Probably the least elegant solution is to use `git patch` and then use whatever other channels to transfer the patch file to the target machine.

1. First, make sure you stage *all* the files you want to include. `git add -u` will *not* add new, untracked files. Using `git add .` from the project root is usually a *bad idea* (❗️) so better stage the untracked files explicitly one by one with `git add newfile` or use the tools provided by your IDE.
2. Create the patch with:

```bash
git diff --patch --staged > wip.patch
```

3. On the other machine (from the repo's root) import the patch using:

```bash
git apply wip.patch
```

ℹ️ <sub>Intellij IDE's provide an easy visual way to both create and apply patches via *Git* > *Patch...*. For vscode there an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paragdiwan.gitpatch) that attempts to do the same.</sub>